# Azure web app scale out - database considerations

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

The scenario is I have a web site running in an azure web app. The site has a database behind it.

What happens if the app service plan that is running the site is scaled out to multiple instances?

will all the site instances hit the same database?

Answer (score 1):

> will all the site instances hit the same database?

In short: Yes, all instances will hit the same database. They're all configured the same, so they'll all use the same database. Without setting up anything like scaling or synchronization, it's expected behavior.

That's why it's a good thing to think about scaling databases too, or having a look at other mechanisms to enable your application to scale out massively like caching, CQRS, Geo Replication, ... .